# Impedance Divider Network

Tags: impedance

Need help with this impedance divider network. I was going to evaluate it like I would resistances but I'm not sure if that's correct. I'm thinking Zc1 has no effect on Vout so it can be ignored and I can just do a voltage divider with ZL and Ze. Is that correct? [image]

Comment: Yes, Zc1 has no effect on Vout. Why don't you just make a quick simulation and verify it?

Comment: @carl I thought about that but I've only used LTSpice one or twice. After I find the cutoff frequency of this circuit by hand ( I need the practice anyways) I think I'll fire up LTSpice and see if I can verify my work.

Comment: @carl you do you have a recommended software for simulation?

Comment: I only have experience with LTSpice which would work fine for a simulation like this.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, $$Z_{C1} $$ has no effect at all, as it is parallel to the voltage source and the voltage divider branch.
You could treat them like resistances, given the linear property of this circuit, where phasors are used.

Answer (score 0):

Redrawing the circuit like this should remove any doubt if \$Z_{c1} \$ has an influence on \$V_{\text{out}} \$ or not

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEaCjx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transfer function is easy to find

$$V_{\text{out}}=V_{\text{in}} \frac{R}{j\omega L+R} =V_{\text{in}} \frac{1}{1+\frac{j\omega L}{R}} \Leftrightarrow  $$
$$\frac{V_{\text{out}}}{V_{\text{in}}} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{j\omega L}{R}} $$

Comment: Yeah I tried that but still doubted myself! I thought the impedance of C is frequency dependent, it could be an open or a short depending on frequency! But then I thought well if it was an unknown resistance, it could be 0 or infinity and I would evaluate it the same way....Regardless after that thought process I needed a sanity check. Thanks.

Comment: @kefffin You are correct, the capacitor can act like an open circuit (\$\omega = 0 \$) or a short circuit (\$ \omega \rightarrow \infty\$). But the thing to notice is that the capacitor is in **parallel** with the LR branch, which means that the voltage across both branches must be the same regardless of the frequency.